# \rotate in NiceTabularX inserts too much space above the contents

Tags: tables, booktabs, nicematrix

I am trying to use `\rotate` inside `\RowStyle` to rotate elements of first row, but it seems too much space is inserted above the contents. How to remove it?

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}m[l]{2.75cm}  @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}}
        
        \toprule
        
        \RowStyle[bold]{\rotate} & Project Editor & Base Editor & Revision Editor & Checker & Browser & Librarian & Controller & Operator
        \\
        
        Project Data/Defaults & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck
        \\
        
        \bottomrule
        
    \end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that a simpler setup does the job. (And using `\RowStyle{\bfseries\rotate}`)

[image: a]

(using nicematrix.sty    2021/09/09 v6.2 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
                
            \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}m[l]{2.75cm} cccccccc @{}} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
            
            \toprule
            
            \RowStyle{\bfseries\rotate} & Project Editor & Base Editor & Revision Editor & Checker & Browser & Librarian & Controller & Operator
            \\
            
            Project Data/Defaults & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck
            \\
            
            \bottomrule
            
        \end{NiceTabular}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

**OR** keeping the same setup of you example but using `\rotatebox` from the package `graphicx` like in the first option. (Instead of `\RowStyle{\rotate})`. The output is the same as before.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for rotatebox   
\newcommand{\rotnd}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        
        \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}m[l]{2.75cm}  @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}X[1, c, m] @{}}
            
            \toprule
            
             & \rotnd{Project Editor} &\rotnd{Base Editor} & \rotnd{Revision Editor}
              & \rotnd{Checker} &\rotnd{Browser} &\rotnd{Librarian} & \rotnd{Controller} &  \rotnd{Operator}
            \\
            
            Project Data/Defaults & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck & \faCheck
            \\
            
            \bottomrule
            
        \end{NiceTabularX}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```